# Browser Incompatible Please Use Mozilla Firefox 3.2 above OR IE 8.0 above

Tags: php, html, css, apache

chrome browser showing this:

Browser Incompatible Please Use Mozilla Firefox 3.2 above OR IE 8.0 above

for website http://test.theartness.com/...

I didn't understand what causing this error. i checked char encoding etc etc. everything..

I have seen in http://web-sniffer.net/ , it seems server sending that response for netscape/mozilla browsers. It is working for Internet explorer7 .. it seems server blocked it for those user agents?

please help me to figure out what is wrong with it?

Best Regards,
Satish Kalepu.

Comment: Put a debug `die()` at the top of the php file you're trying to access. If you see it in Chrome then your problem is most certainly at the code-level. Otherwise, it might be somewhere in your apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a simple user-agent blockage. There might be some script identifying the user-agent and it handles only the stated browsers. Try accessing it using other browsers. You can use http://browsershots.org/ to check how the site behaves on other browsers.

Comment: But we didn't put any such block. but sever peoeple keep saying it is code error.. those hostgator support guy is ass...

Answer (score 0):

As this site is powered by Apache, it is hard to say whether the server or your application is the cause.

Server:  Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/0.9.8m DAV/2 mod_fcgid/2.3.5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635

If the server maintainer says it is code error, ask them for evidence. Otherwise, why cannot it be a server configuration issue?